# How to get physical page in Solaris 11

Tags: debugging, solaris

I am using mdb on Solaris 11. I have opened a file by using " tail -f file_name" command in another ssh session. I got the pid of tail command and Vnode of the file opened by tail command. After getting the Vnode, I fired "walk page" on this file. Unfortunately, I am not getting any pages in walk. How to get Virtual Pages and Physical pages?

Comment: What physical pages are you trying to get?  The pages in the page cache that represent the contents of the file being tailed?

Comment: Yes. I wanted the physical pages which have mapping with virtual pages which we may get from struct vnode of the file.
Here I was not able to get even virtual page. If I could have get any  virtual page, I might have got some virtual to physical mapping of the page. Altimately my goal was to get physical page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done following.

1) Opened the file with 'tail -f'.

2) Get the pid in mdb. Get the Vnode of the opened file.

3) Get the page_t from Vnode_t of the opened file.

4) Left shift to the page number with 0xD, it will give pp2pa effect.

Here are the dcmds in mdb.

> ::pgrep tail

S        PID       PPID       PGID        SID        UID      FLAGS             ADDR NAME

R   2889   2882   2889   2850      0 0x4a004000 0000060013f29890 tail

> 0000060013f29890::pfiles

FD   TYPE            VNODE INFO

0  REG 00000600162f6740 /export/home/chaitanya/OpenSolaris/README.opensolaris

1  CHR 000006001a290400 /devices/pseudo/pts@0:2

2  CHR 000006001a290400 /devices/pseudo/pts@0:2

> 00000600162f6740::walk page

70004781480

700040b0400

> 70004781480::print -at page_t

{

```
70004781480 u_offset_t p_offset = 0x2000

70004781488 struct vnode *p_vnode = 0x600162f6740

70004781490 selock_t p_selock = 0

70004781494 uint_t p_vpmref = 0x11d9d

70004781498 struct page *p_hash = 0x70002f79b00

700047814a0 struct page *p_vpnext = 0x700040b0400

700047814a8 struct page *p_vpprev = 0x700040b0400

700047814b0 struct page *p_next = 0x70004781480

700047814b8 struct page *p_prev = 0x70004781480

700047814c0 ushort_t p_lckcnt = 0

700047814c2 ushort_t p_cowcnt = 0

700047814c4 kcondvar_t p_cv = {

    700047814c4 ushort_t _opaque = 0

}

700047814c6 kcondvar_t p_io_cv = {

    700047814c6 ushort_t _opaque = 0

}

700047814c8 uchar_t p_iolock_state = 0

700047814c9 volatile uchar_t p_szc = 0

700047814ca uchar_t p_fsdata = 0

700047814cb uchar_t p_state = 0x40

700047814cc uchar_t p_nrm = 0x2

700047814cd uchar_t p_vcolor = 0x2

700047814ce uchar_t p_index = 0

700047814cf uchar_t p_toxic = 0

700047814d0 void *p_mapping = 0

700047814d8 pfn_t p_pagenum = 0x80f029

700047814e0 uint_t p_share = 0

700047814e4 uint_t p_sharepad = 0

700047814e8 uint_t p_slckcnt = 0

700047814ec uint_t p_kpmref = 0

700047814f0 struct kpme *p_kpmelist = 0

700047814f8 kmutex_t p_ilock = {

    700047814f8 void *[1] _opaque = [ 0 ]

}
```

}

Left shift to the page number 0x80f029 with 0xD, it will give pp2pa

> 101E052000,100::dump -p

```
           \/ 1 2 3  4 5 6 7  8 9 a b  c d e f  v123456789abcdef
```

101e052000:  75742069 742e2020 4e6f7220 646f2079  ut it.  Nor do y

101e052010:  6f752068 61766520 746f206b 65657020  ou have to keep

101e052020:  7468650a 20202020 206e616d 65206f70  the.     name op

101e052030:  656e736f 6c617269 732e7368 2c206275  ensolaris.sh, bu

101e052040:  74207468 61742773 20746865 206e616d  t that's the nam

101e052050:  65207765 276c6c20 75736520 696e2074  e we'll use in t

101e052060:  68657365 206e6f74 65732e0a 0a202020  hese notes...

101e052070:  20205468 656e206d 616b6520 74686520    Then make the

101e052080:  666f6c6c 6f77696e 67206368 616e6765  following change

101e052090:  7320696e 20796f75 72206f70 656e736f  s in your openso

101e0520a0:  6c617269 732e7368 3a0a0a20 20202d20  laris.sh:..   -

101e0520b0:  6368616e 67652047 41544520 746f2074  change GATE to t

101e0520c0:  6865206e 616d6520 6f662074 68652074  he name of the t

101e0520d0:  6f702d6c 6576656c 20646972 6563746f  op-level directo

101e0520e0:  72792028 652e672e 2c0a2020 20202022  ry (e.g.,.     "

101e0520f0:  74657374 77732229 2e0a0a20 20202d20  testws")...   -